# Vivado Ethernet IP core licensing issue

Tags: fpga, ethernet, xilinx, vivado

I have a PL design in which I included a 10G/25G Ethernet Subsystem IP core from Xilinx configured with BASE-KR, AN/LT logic and FEC logic for Clause 74. When I try to generate the bitstream, I am getting this error:

```
[Common 17-69] Command failed: This design contains one or more cells for which bitstream generation is not permitted:
<encrypted cell> (<encrypted cellview>)
system_i/xxv_ethernet_0/inst/i_system_xxv_ethernet_0_0_top_1/i_system_xxv_ethernet_0_0_ANLT_WRAPPER/i_AN_PCONTROL (<encrypted cellview>)
<encrypted cell> (<encrypted cellview>)
system_i/xxv_ethernet_0/inst/i_system_xxv_ethernet_0_0_top_0/i_system_xxv_ethernet_0_0_ANLT_WRAPPER/i_AN_PCONTROL (<encrypted cellview>)
If a new IP Core license was added, in order for the new license to be picked up, the current netlist needs to be updated by resetting and re-generating the IP output products before bitstream generation.
```

I already tried to Reset Output Products, but it did not help. I only get this error when I enable BASE-KR, AN/LT logic and FEC logic. When I only enable BASE-R, it builds successfully. I am using the trial licenses. I have checked the 10G/25G Ethernet Subsystem documentation, and I have included all licenses which are mentioned. I have attached a picture which shows all my licenses.

What should I do to make it generate the bitstream successfully?

[image: All licenses in my Vivado installation]

Comment: [Did you try a Vivado forum?](https://support.xilinx.com/s/topiccatalog?language=en_US)

Comment: @toolic Yes but I got no reply

Comment: You paid presumably good money for that license, you really should ask whoever sold you the license to get your money's worth or a refund :) The forum is not the way to get licensing support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue a while ago. Generating the output product also did not worked for me. I have multiple licenses from Xilinx/AMD and all licenses were valid and equivalent (same privilege). When I got the error on one vivado, I tried the bitstream on the other vivado and it worked.

I contacted the xilinx to ask for assistance, they told me to remove the license and install it again. But it did not work for me either. Lastly they had to give ma a new license.

May be installing the license again will work for you. If not, you need to contact the xilinx to get a new one. That's my experince.